# Plot a time-complexity graph for a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, matplotlib, graph, time-complexity

So I have this recursion algorithm (for an academic exercise), and want to plot its time complexity.

```
def strToInt(s):
  if s:
    return (ord(s[-1]) - ord('0')) + 10 * strToInt(s[:-1])
  else:
    return 0
```

How do I go about plotting it in Python 3? I did try, but came up with a very irregular and undulating graph which wasn't really conforming to any known time complexity.

This is what I'm getting now

[image]

And the following is the code I'm using to calculate the time:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy as np
import timeit
from functools import partial
import random

def strToInt(s):
      if s:
        return (ord(s[-1]) - ord('0')) + 10 * strToInt(s[:-1])
      else:
        return 0

def plotTC(fn, nMin, nMax, nInc, nTests):
    """
    Run timer and plot time complexity
    """
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(nMin, nMax, nInc):
        N = i
        testNTimer = timeit.Timer(partial(fn, N))
        t = testNTimer.timeit(number=nTests)
        x.append(i)
        y.append(t)
    p1 = pyplot.plot(x, y, 'o')
    #pyplot.legend([p1,], [fn.__name__, ])

# main() function
def main():
    print('Analyzing Algorithms...')

    plotTC(stringToInt, 10, 10000, 10, 10)

    # enable this in case you want to set y axis limits
    #pyplot.ylim((-0.1, 0.5))

    # show plot
    pyplot.show()

# call main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What would be the input to this function? What is the output and in how far does it not meet the expectations?  (*"wasn't really conforming to ___"* is not a good problem description)

Comment: I honestly can see what is wrong with the result or the graph.